# How can I use a key to open and focus on a cleared input element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a user to be able to open up a form with a key stroke and have the input element be focused and clear, so they can start typing immediately. As I have it written below, the form opens on the desired keystroke and the input is focused, but the input starts with the value from the key stroke in it (in my case, 'n'). I want the input to be clear.

```js
function openInputBox() {
    if (event.keyCode == 78) {
        $('#inputForm').show();   //the div with the input element in it
        document.getElementById("input_text").focus();
        document.getElementById("input_text").value = "";
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', openInputBox, false);
```

My best guess is it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the focus() method, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add:

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

inside the **if** block into your handler.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is good, but you did not use the right event, instead of `keydown` you will have to use `keyup`

```js
function openInputBox() {
    if (event.keyCode == 78) {
        $('#inputForm').show();   //the div with the input element in it
        document.getElementById("input_text").focus();
        document.getElementById("input_text").value = "";
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', openInputBox, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputForm">
  <input id="input_text" value="input_text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it solves your problem.
Approve this answer to allow others to benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout for clearing input 
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("input_text").value = "";, 0)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openInputBox() {
    if (event.keyCode == 78) {
        $('#inputForm').show();   //the div with the input element in it
        document.getElementById("input_text").focus();
        document.getElementById("input_text").value = "";
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', openInputBox, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div >
 <input id="input_text"> </input>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

It works with only to add inside the 'if' "event.preventDefault();", try and tell me.

Comment: This worked as well. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: you are welcome, please mark this answer as correct.